# separation of variables 3D cylindrical

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Given the wave equation for the displacement $$u(r,\theta,t)$$ in a circular domain $$0<r<a \text,-\pi<\theta<\pi$$

Use the separation of variables to reduce the problem to an ODE.

$$U_{tt} = C^{2}\Delta u$$

Let $$U(r , \theta  , t) = R(r)\phi (\theta )T(t)$$

$$\bigtriangledown^{2}u = \frac{1}{r}\frac{\delta }{\delta r}(r\frac{\delta u}{\delta r}) + \frac{1}{r^{2}} \frac{\delta ^{2}u}{\delta \theta ^{2}} + \frac{\delta ^{2}u}{\delta t^{2}}$$

$$\frac{\delta u}{\delta r} = \frac{dR}{dr}\phi (\theta)T(t)$$

$$\frac{\delta ^{2}u}{\delta \theta ^{2}} = \frac{d^{2}\phi}{d\theta^{2}}R(r)T(t)$$

$$\frac{\delta ^{2}u}{\delta t^{2}} = \frac{d^{2}\phi}{dt^{2}}R(r)\phi(\theta)
$$
Sustitute into $$\bigtriangledown^{2}u$$ divide by $$u(r,\theta,\phi)$$

We get $$\frac{1}{R(r)}\frac{d}{dr}(r\frac{dR}{dr}) + \frac{1}{r^{2}\phi (\theta)}(\frac{d^{2}}{d\theta^{2}}) + \frac{1}{T(t)}\frac{d^{2}T}{dt^{2}}=0$$

I'm really stuck and really need help. I've no idea what I should do next

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that $u$ and $U$ are the same function.

$$u_{tt} = C^{2}\Delta u = C^{2}\left( \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}) + \frac{1}{r^{2}} \frac{\partial ^{2}u}{\partial \theta ^{2}} + \frac{\partial ^{2}u}{\partial t^{2}}\right)$$

$$\frac{1}{T(t)}\frac{d^{2}T}{dt^{2}}=C^2\left(\frac{1}{R(r)}\frac{d}{dr}(r\frac{dR}{dr}) + \frac{1}{r^{2}\phi (\theta)}(\frac{d^{2}\phi}{d\theta^{2}}) + \frac{1}{T(t)}\frac{d^{2}T}{dt^{2}}\right)$$

$$\frac{C^2}{R(r)}\frac{d}{dr}(r\frac{dR}{dr}) + \frac{C^2}{r^{2}\phi (\theta)}(\frac{d^{2}\phi}{d\theta^{2}}) + \frac{C^2-1}{T(t)}\frac{d^{2}T}{dt^{2}}=0$$

\begin{cases}
     \frac{1}{\phi (\theta)}(\frac{d^{2}\phi}{d\theta^{2}})=c_1\\
     \frac{1}{T(t)}\frac{d^{2}T}{dt^{2}}=c_2\\
     \frac{C^2}{R(r)}\frac{d}{dr}(r\frac{dR}{dr}) + \frac{C^2c_1}{r^2} + (C^2-1)c_2=0\\
   \end{cases}

$c_1$ and $c_2$ are arbitrary constants.

Then, you can solve individually the three ODEs.

Comment: Could you tell me what's your motivation for picking the 3ODEs?

Comment: On what criteria do we pick the 3 ODEs?

Comment: "Separation of variables" means that we try to separate the equation into as many distinct equations as they are variables. Each ODE is expected to contains only one variable. Of course when it is possible. In the present case, it has been possible as shown.

Comment: Upon solving the first ODE in your above post via method of undetermined coefficients,
I arrived at 
$$G(\theta) = C_{1}Cos(\sqrt{\mu} \theta) + C_{2}Sin(\sqrt{\mu} \theta)$$.
Is this my Eigenfunctions?
It's strange that my tutorial sheet solution called $$Cos(\sqrt{\mu} \theta$$ and $$Sin(\sqrt{\mu} \theta$$ the eigenfunctions. 
Where do you think I've went wrong?